# what does 'you may be subject to termination' mean

Tags: meaning

I am interpreting the meaning of a statement.

> You may be subject to termination.

*May be* are the words that change it from a yes-or-no answer to one with variables. Am I correct?

Comment: What does “_May be_ are the words that change it from a yes-or-no answer to one with variables” mean? What is a yes-or-no answer (apart from an answer that is either “Yes” or “No”, which clearly this isn’t—it’s a whole sentence)? And what variables do you mean? That question doesn’t seem to make any sense.

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). I assume OP is interested in the way ***may*** (and ***can***) can be used to express *possibility*, rather than certainty.

Answer (score 1):

You may be fired from your job.
You may be killed. 
You may be considered (for either the above).